# Charset issues in ojdbc7/ojdbc8 vs. correct behaviour in ojdbc6

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, character-encoding, ojdbc

We have an Oracle database with the following charset settings

> SELECT parameter, value FROM nls_database_parameters WHERE parameter like 'NLS%CHARACTERSET'

```
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET: AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8ISO8859P15
```

In this database we have a table with a `CLOB` field, which has a record that starts with the following string, stored obviously in ISO-8859-15: `X²ARB` (here correctly converted to unicode, in particular that 2-superscript is important and correct).

Then we have the following trivial piece of code to get the value out, which is supposed to automatically convert the charset to unicode via globalization support in Oracle:

```
private static final String STATEMENT = "SELECT data FROM datatable d WHERE d.id=2562456";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
         ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(STATEMENT))
    {
        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1).substring(0, 5));
        }
    }
}
```

Running the code prints:

- with `ojdbc8.jar` and `orai18n.jar`: `X�ARB` -- incorrect
- with `ojdbc7.jar` and `orai18n.jar`: `X�ARB` -- incorrect
- with `ojdbc-6.jar`: `X²ARB` -- **correct**

By using `UNISTR` and changing the statement to `SELECT UNISTR(data) FROM datatable d WHERE d.id=2562456` I can bring `ojdbc7.jar` and `ojdbc8.jar` to return the correct value, but this would require an unknown number of changes to the code as this is probably not the only place where the problem occurs.

Is there anything I can do to the client or server configurations to make *all* queries return correctly encoded values without statement modifications?

Comment: Questions: Does this problem also happen when the column type is a VARCHAR2 (instead of a CLOB)? Has this database been upgraded or its characterset altered? Finally orai18n.jar has nothing to do with this. This should work fine without orai18n.jar.

Comment: No it seems to be CLOB specific. What's more, one of the colleagues has just found out that, with a newly downloaded `jodbc6.jr` from the 12.1 driver line its behaviour seems to be inline with that of 7 and 8. Apparently we only get the correct behaviour with the `jodbc-6.jar` which we have had for years with earlier releases of our product. So there must have been a change affecting 6 in a similar manner to 7 and 8 :(

Comment: It definitely looks like a bug in the JDBC thin driver (I assume you're using thin). It could be related to LOB prefetch where the CLOB's length, character set id and the first part of the LOB data is sent inband. This feature was introduced in 11.2. Can you try to disable lob prefetch by setting the connection property "oracle.jdbc.defaultLobPrefetchSize" to "-1"?

Comment: @JeandeLavarene It worked. Please post it as the answer and I will happily accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitely looks like a bug in the JDBC thin driver (I assume you're using thin). It could be related to LOB prefetch where the CLOB's length, character set id and the first part of the LOB data is sent inband. This feature was introduced in 11.2. As a workaround, you can disable lob prefetch by setting the connection property

> oracle.jdbc.defaultLobPrefetchSize

to "-1". Meanwhile I'll follow up on this bug to make sure that it gets fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at [Database JDBC Developer's Guide - Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643)

> The basic Java Archive (JAR) file ojdbc7.jar, contains all the
>   necessary classes to provide complete globalization support for:
>
> - `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` data members of object and collection for the character sets `US7ASCII`, `WE8DEC`, `WE8ISO8859P1`, `WE8MSWIN1252`, and `UTF8`.
>
> To use any other character sets in `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` data members of
>   objects or collections, you must include orai18n.jar in the `CLASSPATH`
>   environment variable:
>
> `ORACLE_HOME/jlib/orai18n.jar`

Comment: We read this section 10 times through before posting this question. As I pointed out in the question, `orai18n.jar` **is** on the classpath.

Comment: I think the statement from Oracle is quite clear: **ojdbc7.jar (and most likely also ojdbc8.jar) does not support WE8ISO8859P15**, i.e. they support only US7ASCII, WE8DEC, WE8ISO8859P1, WE8MSWIN1252, and UTF8. Another solution would be to change the character set of your database, see [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011)

Comment: And for that particular reason we **do** include `orai18n.jar` on the classpath. So it is really totally unclear what you are suggesting (except for altering the DB charset, which is not necessarily a good option).